# Can the (plain) throw statement in C# cause exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception

***Question:*** Can the plain `throw` statement in C# ever cause a new exception in itself?

---

Note that I ask this question out of *curiosity*, not because I have any practical or real-world situation where it would matter much. Also note that my gut feeling and experience tell me that the answer is "No", but I'm looking to validate that answer somehow (see further down on sources I've tried so far).

Here's some sample code to illustrate my question:

```
try
{
    int x = 0, y = 1 / x;
}
catch (Exception outerException)
{

    try
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception innerException)
    {
        // Q: Does this Assert ever fail??
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(outerException.Equals(innerException));
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's any way at all to alter the circumstances such that the `Assert` will fail, without touching the inner `try/catch` block.

What I've tried or was looking to try to answer this:

- Read the [throw (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex.aspx) page on MSDN - no definitive answer;
- Checked part 5.3.3.11 of the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) - which is probably the wrong place to look for this kind of info;
- Glossed through the exceptions that I could try to trigger on the throw statement. The OutOfMemoryException comes to mind, but is kind of hard to trigger at the time of the `throw`.
- Opened up ILDASM to check the generated code. I can see that `throw` translates to a `rethrow` instruction, but I'm lost where to look further to check if that statement can or cannot throw an exception.

This is what ILDASM shows for the inner `try` bit:

```
.try
{
  IL_000d:  nop
  IL_000e:  rethrow
}  // end .try
```

So, to summarize: can a throw statement (used to rethrow an exception) ever *cause* an exception itself?

Comment: Except for satisfying ones curiosity, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Just curiosity I'm afraid, I don't have any exciting (as far as exception can even be exciting) real-world scenario relating to this.

Comment: I do think it could happen if your stack is corrupt. In that case rethrow will try to unwind the stack to the next method with a catch/finally/fault clause. If it can´t it will cause an exception but more likely a ExecutionEngineException which will cause normally the immediate termination of your process.

Comment: ThreadAbortExcepton? No. Reason: ... The thread that calls Abort might block if the thread that is being aborted is in a protected region of code, such as a catch block, finally block, or constrained execution region...

Comment: What about out of an memory exception?  It would extremely rare, but if the memory overhead of the new exception instance pushed the heap over the top, then that could cause another exception, right?  Notice my comment is in the form of a question.  I do not know the answer myself.

Comment: @philologon I was thinking exactly the same, and the [answer by Amit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11205244/419956) also suggests this as an option. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with any way to artificially generate an OutOfMemoryException at a particular point in a program...

Comment: important point to remember here is that re-throw is not something that happens entirely inside CLR. Even for a re-throw CLR invokes kernel's RaiseException method and hence it more or less go through the same logic as other 'mormal' exceptions.

Comment: *Any* statement in a managed program can throw an exception, including `throw;`.  It is not ever the kind of exception you worry about, if such an exception happens then you really *do* want the program to abort.

Comment: @philologon a `throw` *doesn't involve* a new exception instance - it is re-throwing the *existing* exception. So heap shouldn't be an issue. *Stack* could perhaps come into play, if we are (say) somehow **right at the edge** of sanity on the stack-space. But; that is such a convoluted scenario that you probably already have other problems.

Comment: @MarcGravell OutOfMemory is in fact possible (at least as per SSCLI). Please see edit to my answer.

Comment: We just had a situation where `throw;` crashed whole application. Found explanation here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/curth/archive/2008/07/29/stackoverflowexception-and-ironpython.aspx

Answer (score 16):

In my honest opinion, theoretically the assert can 'fail' (practically I don't think so).

How?

Note: Below are just my 'opinion' on the basis of some research I earlier did on SSCLI.

1. An [InvalidProgramException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidprogramexception%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) can occur. This admittedly is highly highly improbable but nevertheless theoretically possible (for instance some internal CLR error may result in the throwable object becoming unavailable!!!!).
2. If CLR does not find enough memory to process the 're-throw' action it will throw an OutOfMemoryException instead (CLR's internal re-throw logic requires to allocate some memory if it is not dealing with 'pre-allocated' exceptions like OutOfMemoryException).
3. If the CLR is running under some other host (for e.g. SQL server or even your own) and the host decides to terminate the Exception re-throw thread (on the basis of some internal logic) ThreadAbortException (known as rude thread abort in this case) will be raised. Though, I am not sure if the Assert will even execute in this case.
4. Custom host may have applied escalation policy to CLR ([ICLRPolicyManager::SetActionOnFailure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164395%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)). In that case if you are dealing with an OutOfMemoryException, escalation policy may cause ThreadAbortException to occur (again rude thread abort. Not sure what happens if policy dictates a normal thread abort).
5. Though @Alois Kraus clarifies that 'normal' thread abort exceptions are not possible, from SSCLI research I am still doubtful that (normal) ThreadAbortException can occur.

Edit:

As I earlier said that the assert can fail theoretically but practically it is highly improbable. Hence it is very hard to develop a POC for this. 
In order to provide more 'evidence', following are the snippets from SSCLI code for processing `rethow` IL instruction which validate my above points.

Warning: Commercial CLR can differ very widely from SSCLI.

1. InvalidProgramException :

   ```
   if (throwable != NULL)
   {
    ...
   }
   else
   {
       // This can only be the result of bad IL (or some internal EE failure).
       RealCOMPlusThrow(kInvalidProgramException, (UINT)IDS_EE_RETHROW_NOT_ALLOWED);
   }
   ```
2. Rude Thread Abort :

   ```
   if (pThread->IsRudeAbortInitiated())
   {
       // Nobody should be able to swallow rude thread abort.
       throwable = CLRException::GetPreallocatedRudeThreadAbortException();
   }
   ```

   This means that if 'rude thread abort' has been initiated, any exception gets changed to rude thread abort exception.
3. Now most interesting of all, the `OutOfMemoryException`. Since rethrow IL instruction essentially re-throws the same Exception object (i.e. `object.ReferenceEquals` returns true) it seems impossible that OutOfMemoryException can occur on re-throw. However, following SSCLI code shows that it is possible:

   ```
    // Always save the current object in the handle so on rethrow we can reuse it. This is important as it
   // contains stack trace info.
   //
   // Note: we use SafeSetLastThrownObject, which will try to set the throwable and if there are any problems,
   // it will set the throwable to something appropiate (like OOM exception) and return the new
   // exception. Thus, the user's exception object can be replaced here.

   throwable = pThread->SafeSetLastThrownObject(throwable);
   ```

   `SafeSetLastThrownObject` calls SetLastThrownObject and if it fails raises `OutOfMemoryException`. Here is the snippet from `SetLastThrownObject` (with my comments added)

   ```
   ...
   if (m_LastThrownObjectHandle != NULL)
   {
      // We'll somtimes use a handle for a preallocated exception object. We should never, ever destroy one of
     // these handles... they'll be destroyed when the Runtime shuts down.
     if (!CLRException::IsPreallocatedExceptionHandle(m_LastThrownObjectHandle))
     {
        //Destroys the GC handle only but not the throwable object itself
        DestroyHandle(m_LastThrownObjectHandle);
     }
   }
   ...

   //This step can fail if there is no space left for a new handle
   m_LastThrownObjectHandle = GetDomain()->CreateHandle(throwable);
   ```

   Above code snippets shows that the throwable object's GC handle is destroyed (i.e frees up a slot in GC table) and then a new handle is created. Since a slot has just been released, new handle creation will never fail until off-course in a highly rare scenario of a new thread getting scheduled just at the right time and consuming up all the available GC handles.

Apart from this all exceptions (including rethrows) are raised through [RaiseException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) win api. The code that catches this exception to prepare the corresponding managed exception can itself raise `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: This answer is great, thanks! The reasoning on several of your points seems logical, and I'm inclined to go along with it. The answer would of course be more definitive if we could add some sample app and steps to reproduce to show that it could happen. I may try to validate one of your scenario's later, and let you know what I found.

Comment: Interesting edit. The tricky question, of course, is : is this behaviour correct and/or compliant ;p Honestly, I don't know the answer to that. But a good read, cheers.

Comment: That is exactly why I put that warning :)....though as far as behavior of commercial CLR is concerned, I guess by attaching a profiler it may be possible to check if it allocates a new handle while processing rethrow IL instruction or not.

Comment: Thanks again Amit. That was a really good and fun answer to read (three times actually, before I got it :D). Awarded you the bounty, even though -like you say- it will be very hard to come up with a POC for this.

Comment: Thanks for a great question...it helped me learn new things as well :)

Answer (score 7):

> Can the plain throw statement in C# ever cause a new exception in itself?

By definition it won't. The very point of `throw;` is to preserve the active exception (especially the stack-trace).

Theoretically an implementation could maybe clone the exception but what would be the point?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! The *"By definition it won't"* was exactly what I was expecting, but as I write in my question I couldn't find any (part of) the/a definition that eliminates my doubts on this. In addition, @AloisKraus' comment to the question suggests it may still be possible to get an exception on throw. Perhaps someone has a reference that could help?

Comment: I think Alois is refuting a suggestion by Gabe. It's still not clear what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the bit you're missing may be the specification for `rethrow`, which is within [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm), partition III, section 4.24:

> **4.24 rethrow – rethrow the current exception**
>
> *Description:*
>   The rethrow instruction is only permitted within the body of a catch handler (see 
>   Partition I). It throws **the same exception** that was caught by this handler.
>   A rethrow does not change the stack trace in the object.
>
> *Exceptions:*
>   The original exception is thrown.

(Emphasis mine)

So yes, it looks like your assertion is guaranteed to work according to the spec. (Of course this is assuming an implementation follows the spec...)

The relevant part of the C# specification is section 8.9.5 (C# 4 version):

> A throw statement with no expression can be used only in a catch block, in which case that statement re-throws the exception that is currently being handled by that catch block.

Which again, suggests that the original exception and *only* that exception will be thrown.

(Section 5.3.3.11 which you referred to is just talking about definite assignment, not the behaviour of the `throw` statement itself.)

None of this invalidates Amit's points, of course, which are for situations which are somewhat outside the scope of what's specified in either place. (When hosts apply additional rules, it's hard for a language specification to take account of them.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, that was about what I was looking for. Unless someone comes up with a counter-example the bounty'll probably go here :-)

Comment: Something I would point out that, this is a specification of the C# language. In actual practice, it depends on the implementation. Mono and the .net CLR might have very different answers and the only way to find out is to actually, and deliberately, test it out in those environments.

Comment: After Amit's edit it felt very hard to choose where to award the bounty. I gave the original bounty to him, and wanted to do another equal 100 rep bounty for this one ("answer deserving extra credit" reason), but for some reason the system only allows me to do a bounty from 200 and up at the moment, so I'll have to look into that once I'm off mobile internet. In any case: many thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @JonSkeet My apologies dear sir, I hadn't read the "[Can I offer a second bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)" rules before I set out to (try to) reward two 100 rep bonuses on different answers to this question; apparently that's not possible. My gratitude once more though for taking the time for this detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion will never fail because there is no code between the rethrow and the assertion.  The only way an exception changes if you catch the exception and cause another one - eg. by having buggy code or "throw new" in your catch clause,.

Comment: I know there is no code between the rethrow and the assertion. That's on purpose, because my question is whether the `throw` itself could cause an exception. I'll try and update my question to clarify this a bit.

Comment: There is no meaningful 'managed' code but CLR still has to run some code to process re-throw which itself may result in some Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Combined with recursion plain `throw` can easily cause `StackOverflowException` on 64-bit platforms.

```
class Program
{
    // expect it to be 10 times less in real code
    static int max = 455;

    static void Test(int i)
    {
        try {
            if (i >= max) throw new Exception("done");
            Test(i + 1);
        }
        catch {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            throw;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try {
            Test(0);
        }
        catch {
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }
}
```

In console:

```
...
2
1
0

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

Some explanation may be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/curth/archive/2008/07/29/stackoverflowexception-and-ironpython.aspx).